# Read directory from Spring Boot's Fat JAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath

I'm trying to read the `resources/configs` directory in my Spring Boot 2 application. Here is the example of the structure of the directory:

```
resources
| configs
| | file1.xml
| | file2.xml
| | ...
```

Code where I'm reading the directory and the nested files:

```
@Value("${app.configs-path}")
String configsPath;

...

Resource configsDirectoryResource = new ClassPathResource(configsPath);
InputStream configsDirectoryStream = configsDirectoryResource.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader configsDirectoryStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(configsDirectoryStream);
BufferedReader configsDirectoryBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(configsDirectoryStreamReader);

List<String> configFileNames = configsDirectoryBufferedReader.lines().collect(toList());
```

And my `application.properties`:

```
app.configs-path=configs
```

When I run my application in IDE, this works fine. The object `configsDirectoryResource` returns stream of filenames, and then I read every nested file. But when I launch the JAR file, `configsDirectoryResource` returns no filenames. However I can read XML files directly, but I'd like to get list of files in runtime.

How can I read the directory or get list of files in the directory which is in the JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` from Spring Framework.

Example code:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/"+configsPath+"/*.xml") ;
for (Resource resource: resources){
    logger.info(resource.getFilename());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have figured out that I can use PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

OK, that was easier than I thought.

```
ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(configsPath + "/*.xml");
```

Then we can get an `InputStream` from each `resource` and work with them.